# How to know when Mulesoft async scope is finished

Tags: asynchronous, mule, mule-esb

I have async scope at the end of main flow. Async scope flow refs for three processes: logging, auditing and inbound payload manipulation. The problem is that now I need to amend the main flow and add a response "mechanism". Response content depends on web service response, which is in one of the async scope flows. So I need to somehow "wait" for every process to finish in the async scope to send a correct response. Could try with setting the thread to sleep but that is not a good solution in my case. Is there some variable/attribute deep in Mule registry that keeps track of async processing or something? At the moment, have multiple possibilities with sleeps but that is fragile and not a good solution overall.

Comment: Probably doesn't help, but maybe Request-Reply scope would work in your scenario? It's async, with a reply. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/request-reply-scope

Comment: Why did you wrote, "probably doesn't help"? What makes you think that? I don't know a lot about queues and the technology, patterns etc

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Async scope is no longer appropriate for that use case. It is not meant to wait or return, so you will need to remove it. You could just execute the request in the flow and save the response as needed.

I strongly advice against using any kind of sleep() as a synchronization method. It is not really a solution, at all. Any changes in timing breaks it.

Comment: I tried removing async scope but there is a lot of code written for async processing so that would result in a big change and quite a bit of work and I don't have a lot of time for it. I fear that it is the only sensible solution...

Comment: You can also try to replace the async by an enricher, to redirect the output to a variable and impact less the rest of the flow.